# Flex game engine

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Up until today, all AS3 based game engine (flixel, pushbutton and etc) that I found from googling are mostly required external framework to do its GUI ... yes there are some samples where I could embedded withing Flex (I did it manually in a game I did) but there is no game engine that comes naturally with Flex.
If anyone out there could point me to this kind of Flex game engine please help me.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: The Flex Framework is a UI Framework, and I would think twice about using it for games due to the overhead it brings to the table.  I would suspect that all the game engines are AS3 and can be used in conjunction w/ the Flex framework as needed. ( I know PushButton can be ).

Comment: That's exactly what I said ... most AS3 based game engine could be embedded into Flex (I did this) ... but that's not what I asked. :)

Comment: Flex just wouldn't be fast enough to do anything with movement/animation. UIComponents (flex's core for displaying stuff) are by nature HEAVEY. That's because they do so much like focus management, layout etc. The one exception to this might be like... a Chess game or other games requiring almost no animation, physics, hit detection, etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There really aren't any. Flex is hardly documented, let alone having a game engine written for it.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably never going to see a game framework that is built specifically for Flex.  Flex isn't really geared towards games, it's geared towards form based business applications.  The Flex team wouldn't write a game framework, that's not their focus.

There are some nice things about Flex such as MXML layouts, binding, etc... but the problem you run into is that most of your CPU cycles are going to running your UI (UIComponent) instead of your game simulation.  This becomes extremely noticeable when you venture into the mobile space.

Cheers,
Nate